# How to add decimals to formal grammar?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

I have a formal language that describes digit production like

```
<digit> ::= 0|1|2|...|9
```

and I need to intruduce fraction to write decimals like `3.14` and so on

What did I do:

```
<frac> ::= <digit><frac> | .<digit><frac> | <digit>
```

I feel that the `.<digit><frac>` part is wrong, as every time we go this production we can substitute this part and get more than a single dot for the decimal part, which is wrong? What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly produce a formal grammar, you should designate a non-terminal for each different part of a decimal. Here is a sample grammar in Backus–Naur form that also uses square brackets for optional items.

```
            <decimal> ::= [<sign>]<nonnegative_decimal>
               <sign> ::= - | +
<nonnegative_decimal> ::= <nonnegative_integer>[<fractional_part>]
<nonnegative_integer> ::= <positive_integer> | 0
   <positive_integer> ::= <nonzero_digit>[<digits>]
    <fractional_part> ::= .<digits>
             <digits> ::= <digit>[<digits>]
              <digit> ::= <nonzero_digit> | 0
      <nonzero_digit> ::= 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

It can be made more compact as the following.

```
            <decimal> ::= [ - | + ]<nonnegative_decimal>
<nonnegative_decimal> ::= <nonnegative_integer>[.<digits>]
<nonnegative_integer> ::= <nonzero_digit>[<digits>] | 0
             <digits> ::= <digit>[<digits>]
              <digit> ::= <nonzero_digit> | 0
      <nonzero_digit> ::= 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

Please note that the above grammar defines a decimal as a string that starts with a possible sign followed by an integer, possibly followed by a dot and some digits, where only 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9 are allowed in an integer or digits and where an integer must not start with 0. Many other kinds of decimals are used, too.

Answer (score 1):

A decimal number is either a sequence of digits, or a sequence of digits followed by a decimal point and a second sequence of digits.

Your analysis of your attempt is wrong: it matches things like `.1.2.3.456`.